# Attempting to create a JVM in a process unexpectedly crashes due to OOM

Tags: java, c++, windows, java-native-interface

I'm trying to debug an ODBC driver which is implemented partially in Java (using C++ & JNI).

We have a test tool which is used to run tests against the driver, but when it tries to load it, during the call to `SQLAllocHandle`, the initialization of the driver calls `JNI_CreateJavaVM` to initialize the JVM, but that crashes with an access violation at address 0 somewhere inside of jvm.dll, outputting the following to stdout/stderr:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 176 bytes for Arena::Amalloc
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\perforce\Drivers\JavaInternalTest\Maintenance\10.3\Product\Tests\Touchstone\API\hs_err_pid27124.log
```

the contents of the mentioned file:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 176 bytes for Arena::Amalloc
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
#   JVM is running with Unscaled Compressed Oops mode in which the Java heap is
#     placed in the first 4GB address space. The Java Heap base address is the
#     maximum limit for the native heap growth. Please use -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress
#     to set the Java Heap base and to place the Java Heap above 4GB virtual address.
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (allocation.cpp:550), pid=27124, tid=0x0000000000005f28
#
# JRE version:  (8.0_392-b08) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.392-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000002b574012800):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=24360, stack(0x000000c5b5630000,0x000000c5b5730000)]

Stack: [0x000000c5b5630000,0x000000c5b5730000]
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x000002b574012800 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=24360, stack(0x000000c5b5630000,0x000000c5b5730000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None
```

The strange thing is that when I try to load the same driver using another program (Microsoft's ancient ODBCTest tool), it loads just fine.

Using `-XX:HeapBaseMinAddress` (I tried `4g`, `8g`, and `40g`) didn't seem to do anything, but if I pass `-XX:-UseCompressedOops` like suggested in https://poonamparhar.github.io/out_of_memory_on_64_bit_platform/, I get the same stdout/stderr message, but the created log file has more information:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 176 bytes for Arena::Amalloc
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (allocation.cpp:550), pid=38828, tid=0x0000000000009024
#
# JRE version:  (8.0_392-b08) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.392-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 )
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000019beccf2800):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=36900, stack(0x000000240c200000,0x000000240c300000)]

Stack: [0x000000240c200000,0x000000240c300000]
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x0000019beccf2800 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=36900, stack(0x000000240c200000,0x000000240c300000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (0 events):
No events


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff727390000 - 0x00007ff7296d4000     C:\perforce\SimbaTestTools\Touchstone\Maintenance\10.1\C++\build\vs2019-x64-Debug\Touchstone.exe
0x00007ffe67d10000 - 0x00007ffe67f27000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffe66f40000 - 0x00007ffe67004000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffe656b0000 - 0x00007ffe65a56000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffe66320000 - 0x00007ffe66391000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffe67010000 - 0x00007ffe67127000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffe65a60000 - 0x00007ffe65abe000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00007ffe676b0000 - 0x00007ffe67757000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffd341c0000 - 0x00007ffd343e1000     C:\perforce\SimbaTestTools\Touchstone\Maintenance\10.1\C++\build\vs2019-x64-Debug\sbicuuc71_64.dll
0x00007ffe67130000 - 0x00007ffe671e1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffe67260000 - 0x00007ffe67305000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffd599b0000 - 0x00007ffd59a78000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ODBC32.dll
0x00007ffe65330000 - 0x00007ffe65496000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
0x00007ffe65590000 - 0x00007ffe656a1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffe66450000 - 0x00007ffe665fe000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffe65140000 - 0x00007ffe65166000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffe666a0000 - 0x00007ffe666c9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffe65210000 - 0x00007ffe65328000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffe65170000 - 0x00007ffe6520a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffe64de0000 - 0x00007ffe64dea000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DPAPI.DLL
0x0000019be8cc0000 - 0x0000019beaaa0000     C:\perforce\SimbaTestTools\Touchstone\Maintenance\10.1\C++\build\vs2019-x64-Debug\sbicudt71_64.dll
0x00007ffe66a80000 - 0x00007ffe66ab1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ffe648f0000 - 0x00007ffe64918000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x00007ffe654a0000 - 0x00007ffe6551a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000182d10000     C:\perforce\Drivers\JavaInternalTest\Maintenance\10.3\Product\Bin\w2016\vs2022\debug64md\InternalTestJNIDSIODBC64.dll
0x00007ffd33f10000 - 0x00007ffd341ba000     C:\perforce\Drivers\JavaInternalTest\Maintenance\10.3\Product\Bin\w2016\vs2022\debug64md\sbicuin71_64.dll
0x00007ffd34c10000 - 0x00007ffd34cf1000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
0x00007ffe5f110000 - 0x00007ffe5f11f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_1D.dll
0x00007ffe3e1c0000 - 0x00007ffe3e1ee000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140D.dll
0x00007ffd33800000 - 0x00007ffd33a21000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ucrtbased.dll
0x00007ffe63ad0000 - 0x00007ffe63adc000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll
0x00007ffe49300000 - 0x00007ffe4931d000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140.dll
0x00007ffe45e20000 - 0x00007ffe45e2c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_1.dll
0x000000005c900000 - 0x000000005d198000     C:\Program Files\OpenLogic\jdk-8.0.392.08-hotspot\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffe66600000 - 0x00007ffe66608000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffe2e760000 - 0x00007ffe2e769000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffe648a0000 - 0x00007ffe648aa000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffe57420000 - 0x00007ffe57454000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x000000005c820000 - 0x000000005c8f2000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR100.dll
0x00007ffe640a0000 - 0x00007ffe640e2000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SSPICLI.DLL
0x00007ffe5f0f0000 - 0x00007ffe5f0ff000     C:\Program Files\OpenLogic\jdk-8.0.392.08-hotspot\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00007ffdff350000 - 0x00007ffdff379000     C:\Program Files\OpenLogic\jdk-8.0.392.08-hotspot\jre\bin\java.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -XX:-UseCompressedOops 
java_command: <unknown>
java_class_path (initial): C:\perforce\Drivers\JavaInternalTest\Maintenance\10.3\Product\Lib\JavaInternalTest.jar
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\OpenLogic\jdk-8.0.392.08-hotspot\
PATH=C:\Program Files\OpenLogic\jdk-8.0.392.08-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Python312\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python312\;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.21.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.8.101-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.392.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.392.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-8.0.392.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-17.0.8.101-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-11.0.21.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-8.0.392.8-hotspot\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Perforce\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Microsoft Application Virtualization\Sequencer\;C:\Users\matthew.wozniczka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\ripgrep-13.0.0-i686-pc-windows-msvc;C:\Users\matthew.wozniczka\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\OpenLogic\jdk-8.0.392.08-hotspot\jre\bin\server;
USERNAME=matthew.wozniczka
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 186 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 11 , 64 bit Build 22621 (10.0.22621.2506)

CPU:total 12 (initial active 12) 

Memory: 4k page, physical 33198800k(13777260k free), swap 44733136k(15863304k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.392-b08) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_392-392-b08), built on Oct 18 2023 07:33:07 by "Administrator" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Wed Jan 03 18:54:47 2024
timezone: Pacific Standard Time
elapsed time: 0.020431 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

I have plenty of ram & disk space free, and visual studio's diagnostics window is telling me I'm only using ~21 megs of memory at the point of the crash (Not sure how accurate that is).

I was trying to figure out what the memory mappings in the process were at the time of the crash (like you can do w/ `info proc mappings` in GDB on linux, for example), but I couldn't figure out how to do it from Visual Studio (2020), and the only tool I found, VMMap, seemed to hang when I tried to use it in the process which was paused in Visual Studio (I'm guessing there's a limitation where it can't do its work on a process which is already being debugged by something else?)

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what to look into next?

Edit: I just installed OpenJDK 11.0.21+9, and it works in both programs when using that...

Comment: As a side comment, it's pretty disappointing that it crashes simply due to not having enough memory to initialize the JVM...

Comment: Well, if there's insufficient memory there's really not that many other choices besides a crash. Terminating nicely with a 0 exit code, instead of a fiery explosion, has mostly a cosmetic benefit. One way or another the process will crash. It has no other options. The only difference is the choice between a nice bowtie with a "stick a fork in me, I'm done" card, and a flaming wreck.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - What's preventing `JNI_CreateJavaVM` from returning `JNI_ENOMEM` (One of the defined return values)?

Personally, I'd rather get an error in, say, Excel when this causes the driver to fail to load, rather than just crashing the application.

Comment: probably much as it says , the use of the calls return data to a variable from Arena::Amalloc probably does not have calloc malloc or sizeof (probably not calloc) or maybe realloc

Comment: @SamuelMarchant - Could you rephrase your comment? I didn't understand.

Comment: Probably because it doesn't even get a choice to do so. Its outrageous attempt to allocate <X> bytes of RAM results in a hearty laughter from the kernel, and a SIGKILL to the process, as the reward.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - Linux's OOM-killer (and other analogous systems) are indeed a terrible, terrible idea. Good thing Windows doesn't work that way (by default)

Comment: Complex scenario and not enough debugging/reproduction details. Not even a stacktrace?

Comment: the stack goes directly from my code's call to `JNI_CreateJavaVM` into jvm.dll, and I don't have symbols, so a stack trace wouldn't do much good.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/eIuLsdz Here's a picture of it